# Redirect to `error/404` on invalid culture or invalid route

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing, asp.net-core-localization, asp.net-core-7.0

On an NET Core 7 Razor Pages project I am using route localization.

In `Program.cs` I have the following:

```
  builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(x => {
    x.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt");
    x.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("pt") };
    x.SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("pt") };
    x.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { 
      RouteDataStringKey = "culture",
      UIRouteDataStringKey = "culture",
      Options = x
    }); 
  });

WebApplication application = builder.Build();

application.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");

application.UseRequestLocalization();

// ...
```

My Razor Pages are as follows:

```
@page "/{culture?}/contact"
@model ContactModel
```

So when `culture` is defined the page would be in that culture.

When is it not defined then the page gets the default culture, e.g., "PT".

The problem is handling the errors. I am using Status Code redirect:

```
application.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
```

If, for example, I visit a non existent page then I am redirected to `/error/4o4`:

```
@page "/errors/{code?}"
@model ErrorModel
```

However if I try to access "/abc" that is not a valid culture or a valid page I am not redirected to `/error/4o4`.

I should be redirected to `/error/4o4` if I access a route that starts with a invalid culture or a invalid page route.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However if I try to access "/abc" that is not a valid culture or a
> valid page I am not redirected to /error/4o4

I am not sure why you are not redirecting to the `non-existent` page. I have tried to reproduce your issue and I am getting the expected error page as you can see below:

[image]

**Possible Reason:**

Make sure you have register below attribute on your `program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();
```

**Note:** Not sure if you already have these. In addtion, please check the page name spelled correctly `@page "/errors/{code?}"` then it would be like `application.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/errors/{0}");`

> I should be redirected to /error/4o4 if I access a route that starts
> with a invalid culture or a invalid page route.How can I do this?

This is the main point I am interested in. There is no straight forward solution for this. However, I have a workaround for you.

**Implementation:**

To meet your requirement, I will consider two things:

1. I will check the route parameter on `HttpContext`
2. Based on `HttpContext` value I will check the `CultureInfo`

Using Middleware We can do that:

**Middleware:**

```cs
public class CheckCultureAndRouteThenRedirect
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        public CheckCultureAndRouteThenRedirect(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)


       
        {
          
            var routeURL = context.Request.Path.ToString();
            var host = context.Request.Host;
            var fullRoute= host + routeURL;
            if (routeURL != "/" && !routeURL.Contains("error"))
            {
                Uri requestedRoute = new Uri(fullRoute);

                string[] firstRoute = requestedRoute.Segments;
                string cultureRequested = firstRoute[1];
                var culture = cultureRequested.TrimEnd('/');


                CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

                if (!cultureInfo.Name.Contains(culture))
                {

                    context.Response.Redirect("/error/404");
                    await context.Response.CompleteAsync();

                }
            }

            await next(context);
        }
    }
```

**Note:**

Make sure you have registered the middlware in `program.cs` file as below:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<CheckCultureAndRouteThenRedirect>();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I have the same configuration as you but I found out why I am not redirected to "/errors/404" if I type "/abc" which is not a valid culture or a valid page: I have the homepage `Index.cshtl` with `@page "/{{culture?}". The reason why I am adding `{{culture?}`as optional in all my pages is because if `culture` is not provided than would fallback for default `culture`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Even if you use `CheckCultureAndRouteThenRedirect` also doesn't work?

Comment: I just tested the middleware and it works. Is it possible when culture is null to redirect to the same page but with the default culture? Only if culture is defined and is invalid then is redirected to 404?

Comment: I believe both scenario can be achieved. As our main goal for this question was something else so would be great to have another seperate question for that concern. Would happy to assit on that as well.

Comment: I already have such a StackOverflow question of a Middleware I am trying to create: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791623/redirect-to-same-page-with-an-extra-parameter. Any help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: Okay sir, I will check if I can asist, thanks for sharing.