# Redirect to same page with an extra parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing, asp.net-core-7.0

I am using Request Localization in a NET Core 7 and Razor Pages application:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
  options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt");
  options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("pt") };
  options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { 
    RouteDataStringKey = "culture",
    UIRouteDataStringKey = "culture",
    Options = options
  }); 
});

WebApplication application = builder.Build();

application.UseRouting();
application.MapRazorPages();

application.UseRequestLocalization();

// ...
```

A few of my razor pages are:

```
Index: @page "/{culture?}"     Example: /pt

About: @page "/{culture?}/about"   Example: /pt/about
```

When the `culture` is `null` or invalid I want to redirect to same page with default culture.

I am trying to do this using a middleware:

```
public class RedirectUnsupportedCulturesMiddleware {

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string _routeDataStringKey;

    public RedirectUnsupportedCulturesMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> monitor) {

        RequestLocalizationOptions options = monitor.Value;
        _next = next;
        var provider = options.RequestCultureProviders
            .Select(x => x as RouteDataRequestCultureProvider)
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        _routeDataStringKey = provider.RouteDataStringKey;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {

        var requestedCulture = context.GetRouteValue(_routeDataStringKey)?.ToString();
        var cultureFeature = context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();

        var actualCulture = cultureFeature?.RequestCulture.Culture.Name;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedCulture) ||
            !string.Equals(requestedCulture, actualCulture, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            var newCulturedPath = GetNewPath(context, actualCulture);
            context.Response.Redirect(newCulturedPath);
            return;
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }

    private string GetNewPath(HttpContext context, string newCulture) {

        var routeData = context.GetRouteData();

        var router = routeData.Routers[0];
        var virtualPathContext = new VirtualPathContext(
            context,
            routeData.Values,
            new RouteValueDictionary { { _routeDataStringKey, newCulture } });

        return router.GetVirtualPath(virtualPathContext).VirtualPath;
    }
}
```

When I access the home page, e.g "/", I get an exception in the following:

```
var router = routeData.Routers[0];
```

**Questions**

1. How to solve this?
2. Can I use a 301 redirect from thee middleware?
3. Can I use the Net Core `UseRewriter` to accomplish the same objective?

Comment: Hi @Miguel Moura, `When the culture is null or invalid I want to redirect to same page with default route.` what is the default route you want?

Comment: I meant “redirect to same page with the default culture” not “default route”. That was a typing error …

Comment: Have a look [ASP.NET Core Culture Route Parameter](https://medium.com/@dmitrysikorsky/asp-net-core-culture-route-parameter-4e1310cabacc)

Comment: @DmitryPavlov  I checked that post before. I would like to use the new Net Core `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` but article uses a custom provider. It has a link to another post that uses `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider`but with MVC and not Razor Pages. And I'm having some problems converting code from MVA to Razor Pages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

1.Custom `IPageRouteModelConvention` to map the route and then **no need modify** page route like `@page "/{culture?}/xxx"`

```
public class CustomCultureRouteRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        List<SelectorModel> selectorModels = new List<SelectorModel>();
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
            selectorModels.Add(new SelectorModel()
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Template = "/{culture}" + "/" + template
                }
            });
        }
        foreach (var m in selectorModels)
        {
            model.Selectors.Add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

2.Add this page conventions in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(opts =>
{
    opts.Conventions.Add(new CustomCultureRouteRouteModelConvention());  //add this...
});
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
    opt =>
    {
       var supportCulteres = new List<CultureInfo>
       {
           new CultureInfo("pt"),
           new CultureInfo("fr")
       };
       opt.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt");
       opt.SupportedCultures = supportCulteres;
       opt.SupportedUICultures = supportCulteres;
       opt.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider()); //add this...
   });
```

3.The order of the middleware

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


//app.UseRequestLocalization();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseRequestLocalization();  //be sure add here......
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it does not solve my problems:
1 - When I type a route with invalid culture "/xyx/about" I am not redirected to default culture "pt" of the same page;
2 . Now when I click a link to go to "About" page the url becomes "/about?culture=en" instead of "/en/about". I am using the following to generate the links: `<a asp-page="About" asp-route-culture="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName">About</a>`
Can this be solved? I was also trying conventions but wasn't able to solve the problems.

Comment: Hi @MiguelMoura, if i use the invalid culture, it will display the page with default culture, do you mean you also want the route to be `pt/xxx`? For your second question, my url generate the correct url with `/pt/about`.

Comment: Hi: 1. yes I would like the route to be pt/xxx. 2. I don't know why but when I type an invalid culture in the url I am always redirected to EN even if my default culture is PT. 3. How do create an anchor tag witch URL would be "/current_cutlure/about"? All my anchor tags when clicked lead to "/about?culture=current_culture" and not "/current_cutlure/about"